# Total Count In Django

Tags: django, count, django-templates

I have models, views & template in Django and want to display the total count of category.

```
class Entry (models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    category = models.ForeignKey('entry.Category')

class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True, related_name='children')

def category(request):
    category = Category.objects.all()
    return render_to_response('category.html', locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request))

<ul>
{% for category in category %}
<li><a href="{{ category.slug }}">{{ category.title }}</a> ({{ category.entry_set.all.count }})</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Current output:

**-Category 1 (0)**

--Sub Category 1 (3)

--Sub Category 2 (6)

And desire output is like this:

**-Category 1 (9)**

--Sub Category 1 (3)

--Sub Category 2 (6)

How to get that output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by using Django-MPTT and update my view & template like this:

views.py:

```
def category(request):
    category = Category.tree.add_related_count(Category.objects.all(), Entry, 'category', 'cat_count', cumulative=True)
    return render_to_response('category.html', locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

category.html:

```
{% recursetree category %}
<ul>
<a href="{{ node.slug }}">{{ node.title }} ({{ node.cat_count }})</a>
{% if not node.is_leaf_node %}
<li class="children">
{{ children }}
</li>
{% endif %}
</ul>
{% endrecursetree %}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `category.entry_set.count` instead of `category.entry_set.all.count`.

Also, you are using same variable name `category` for referencing multiple values, you may want to change that.

Update template as:

```
<ul>
{% for cat in category %}
<li><a href="{{ cat.slug }}">{{ cat.title }}</a> ({{ cat.entry_set.count }})</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I still get zero value

Comment: @pije, Do you have appropriate data?

Comment: Not sure what's appropriate data in django as I am PHP developer before.

Comment: @pije, use django python shell and see what values do you get for similar code.